# place the data according to the header in csv file

Tags: python, regex, date, csv, python-3.x

Hi guys i'm new to python scripting, i need a small help in my script

i have huge log file like this

```
xxxx = "qqqqqqq  5466 78455" yyyy = "wwww" zzzz = "hhhh" mmmm = "aaaa"
xxxx = "qqqqqqq  8795 32133" yyyy = "wwww" zzzz = "hhhh" mmmm = "aaaa"
xxxx = "qqqqqqq  5995 21384" zzzz = "hhhh" mmmm = "aaaa"
xxxx = "qqqqqqq  6546 12346" yyyy = "wwww" zzzz = "hhhh" mmmm = "aaaa"
xxxx = "qqqqqqq  7895 13246" yyyy = "wwww" zzzz = "hhhh" mmmm = "aaaa"
xxxx = "qqqqqqq 64654 94343" yyyy = "wwww" mmmm = "aaaa"
```

and this file go on.....

i need the output as:

```
 xxxx          yyyy       zzzz         mmmm
  qqqqqqq        wwww       hhhh         aaaa 
  qqqqqqq        wwww       hhhh         aaaa
  qqqqqqq                   hhhh         aaaa
  qqqqqqq        wwww       hhhh         aaaa
  qqqqqqq        wwww       hhhh         aaaa
  qqqqqqq        wwww                    aaaa
```

and my code is

```
import csv
import re
fread = open(fileread, "r")
resultFile = open("out4.csv",'w')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile)
try:
     for line in fread:
            regex = re.findall(r'"(.+?)"',line)
            wr.writerow(regex) 
finally:
    fread.close()
    resultFile.close()
```

for this code i'm getting the output as :

```
  qqqqqqq        wwww       hhhh         aaaa 
  qqqqqqq        wwww       hhhh         aaaa
  qqqqqqq        hhhh       aaaa
  qqqqqqq        wwww       hhhh         aaaa
  qqqqqqq        wwww       hhhh         aaaa
  qqqqqqq        wwww       aaa
```

i don't know how to get the header and place the data according to the header....

pls help me or get me the hint of how to do it

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Try Pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Answer (score 0):

If only the `yyyy` and `zzzz` values are optional in your given text file, you can use a complex pattern to match the entire line:

```
r'(?:xxxx = "([^"]+)") (?:yyyy = "([^"]+)" )(?:zzzz = "([^"]+)" )?(mmmm = "([^"]+)")'
```